# sql like query issue

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to fetch data , which has the description keyword at the start or in the middle or at the end.

Following is my query

```
like '%" + description + "' or '" + description + "%' or '%" + description + "%'
```

Problem is it is returning irrelevant data.

E.g if i have given 'as' in description then it also choses 'cake' in result.

```
Description
------------------------------------------------------------
asd
asdasd
cake
Naw
Tast
ad
```

Comment: Why don't you stick to `'%" + description + "%'`

Comment: isn't `like '%" + description + "%'` enough?

Comment: ends with the description keyword, start or in middle. use simple query"  where description like % $description % "

Comment: Ok, i edited my query, it works fine except one problem, that is i have given now 'as' it chose only two records 'ad','asdasd'. Y it is picking 'ad'

Comment: can you show the complete query code?

Comment: "select e_date , c_name,description , payment from entry_child where (description like '%" + description + "%') and (e_date >= '" + fromdate + "' and e_date <= '" + todate + "')";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only write

```
like '%" + description + "%'
```

With this you can retrieve data that you want because it take data that start, string in the middle and finish with that string without using or statement.

Comment: Solved my problem but still have a issue

Comment: What problem do you have now?

Comment: Ok, i edited my query, it works fine except one problem, that is i have given now 'as' it chose only two records 'ad','asdasd'. Y it is picking 'ad'

Comment: (description like '%" + description + "%') and (e_date >= '" + fromdate + "' and e_date <= '" + todate + "')"

Comment: you have asd and asdasd... if you type as is correct that taken asd and asdasd.. you haven't ad I see--

Answer (score 1):

just put

```
LIKE '%" + description + "%'
```

by the way, if you have multiple "or" statements, you have to rewrite the column name and the comparator

```
mycolumn like '%" + description + "' or
mycolumn like '" + description + "%' or 
mycolumn like '%" + description + "%'
```

but this isn't needed in that case.

You might also look at prepared statements !

Comment: I am using this is report , so (OleDbDataAdapter) i dont know how to do this paramterization in this

Answer (score 1):

since you have this `'%" + description + "%'`

why not directly

```
SELECT..FROM...WHERE columnName LIKE '%" + description + "%'"
```

buy your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. use parameters instead

```
"
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE columnName LIKE @description"
```

then define parameters in your query

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", "%" + description + "%")
```

Comment: Actually i am using this in reporting so i cant use the above.

Comment: ok, use only one condition since `WHERE columnName LIKE '%" + description + "%'` handles both starting and ending characters